# makebst 'initial error'

Tags: errors, custom-bib

I'm trying to make a customized bibliography style, and I have downloaded `makebst`. I open the `makebst.tex` file in my TeXMaker-editor, and press LaTeX (<kbd>F2</kbd>) to compile. But then I get this error:

```
! Emergency stop.
<read 1>
l.214 Do you want a description of the usage? {NO}
** *(cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)
```

And for you to know: 214 says:

```
\ask{\yn}{Do you want a description of the usage? (NO)}
```

I'm not sure what I am supposed to do?? Can anyone help me? As I read it, some kind of dialog box should appear?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: I know the following hint isn't related to your question. Instead of `makebst` I really recommend the usage of `biblatex`. It is more flexible and allows you to specify your requirements.

Comment: I concur with Marco Daniel, [`biblatex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) is the way to go! :)

Comment: You must run TeX over `makebst.tex` in interactive mode from a command shell.

Comment: (I know I should avoid writing for clarification, but I'm very new into this board.) egreg - can you rewrite that in a "very easy way". I'm not really into "programming". I'm using mac btw. (I'll look at biblatex too)

Answer (score 3):

(From an old comment.)

Using `makebst` is about as straightforward as it can get.  Simply open a terminal and type:

```
tex makebst
```

At that point you will be prompted to answer a number of questions to determine what style you need.

It does a surprisingly good job, but you are likely to find the resulting style more suited to your needs if you are not expecting to conform to the more complex demands that humanities styles tend to expect and require.  If you work in the humanities (and even if you don't), you will find `biblatex` (and `biber`) much more suited to your needs.  There already exist a great variety of 'base' styles as well as more specialized ones (e.g., APA, Chicago, MLA).

`biblatex` is fairly easy to customize, if you find a base style that is fairly close to what you require, but if you are not 'into 'programming"', you will need to use an existing style or rely on the kindness of strangers. Luckily there are many kind strangers here who like tweaking `biblatex`.